# Parsing from XML -> JSON -> Php Object

Tags: php, json, xml

I'm going to create php object to build my own table from response xml api.

I tried to convert the API response XML into Json, but I can't turn it into a php object. PHP is new for me...

```php
class ParserMy {
        public static function jsonToDebug($jsonText = '')
    {
        $arr = json_decode($jsonText, true);
        $html = "";
        if ($arr && is_array($arr)) {
            echo "<pre>".json_encode($arr,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)."</pre>";
          //  $html .= self::_arrayToHtmlTableRecursive($arr);
        }
        return $html;
    }



}


$url = "....url....";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$json = json_encode($xml);

echo ParserMy::jsonToDebug($json);
```

I wanna convert json or xml response into array of objects but there are more attributes...that I can't manage.

Example from this json into:

```
{
    "station": [
        {
            "@attributes": {
                "id": "27",
                "co": "SH",
                "co_name": "Shell",
                "lat": "",
                "lng": "",
                "name": "Shell - QE",
                "address": "",
                "street_code": "",
                "highway_id": "",
                "highway": "",
                "zip": "",
                "city": "",
                "city_name": "",
                "provincia": "",
                "fuels": "bde",
                "phone": "",
                "status": "AP",
                "neighbour_distance": "",
                "insertion_date": "2008-01-01 00:00",
                "last_updated": "2013-12-31 00:00",
                "latest_price_change": "",
                "highres": "0",
                "photos": "0",
                "tags": "",
                "user": "qe"
            },
            "reports": {
                "report": [
                    {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "price": "1.666",
                            "date": "2018-04-09 00:00:00",
                            "service": "CS",
                            "fuel": "diesel"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "@attributes": {
                            "price": "1.782",
                            "date": "2018-04-09 00:00:00",
                            "service": "CS",
                            "fuel": "benzina"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

into unique object alias

```html
id: 27
co: SH
co_name:    Shell
name:   Shell - QE
address:    
street_code:    
zip:    
city:   
city_name:  
provincia:  
phone:  
fuels:  bde
tags:   
lat:    
lng:    
insertion_date: 2008-01-01 00:00
last_updated:   2013-12-31 00:00
latest_price_change:    
diesel (CS) 1.666 il 2018-04-09 00:00:00 cert:
benzina (CS)    1.782 il 2018-04-09 00:00:00 cert:
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you parse xml using `simplexml_load_file()` it returns an `object` of class `SimpleXMLElement` with properties containing the data held within the XML document, or FALSE on failure.

```
    $phpObject = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

You can directly cast it to `array`:

```
    $array = (array) $phpObject;
```

or `json`:

```
    $json = json_encode($phpObject);
```

you can check a working exmple here http://ideone.com/MRMW1E

Comment: Ehm I've another question... but if you try this url http://www.testcolan.it/campit/test_xml.php you can see output of dumped $array. I would get attributes array for each child ... how can I do that?

Comment: @MaddalenaTinti You should post a new question cause this is how **stackoverflow** works. Your question may help others who wanted to ask same question.

Comment: ok ok ... i solved this ... if you watch the url above it works now....thanks again @Aakash Tushar